# Configure publicPath in rollup.config.js for Svelte

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, svelte, rollupjs

I try to serve Svelte front-end application with Nginx reverse proxy. All application files are placed in the Docker container. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.18.2-slim AS build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm ci && npm run build

FROM node:14.18.2-alpine

WORKDIR /srv/app

COPY --from=build --chown=node:node /usr/src/app /srv/app

USER node

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]

EXPOSE 5000
```

Package.json scripts are as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "serve": "sirv public --no-clear -s --host 0.0.0.0"
}
```

I need my application available at `https://example.com/app`, so I have configured Nginx the following way:

```
upstream app {
  server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

location /app/ {
    proxy_pass http://app/;

    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
```

Unfortunately most of requests are pointing to *publicPath* or *basePath* of `/` (e.g. `https://example.com/build/bundle.css`)

Is there a way to configure *publicPath* for Rollup to point at `/app` (e.g. `https://example.com/app/build/bundle.css`)?

As far as I understand the most obvious place to configure *publicPath* would be in `rollup.config.js` just like in Svelte-cli. But it seems that [rollup-plugin-svelte](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-svelte) doesn't provide such configuration option.

Can you please help to find a way to get thing right?